# All paths or activities lead to the center of things

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one word that means "All paths or activities lead to the center of things. "

Comment: Is this a word you know exists and you're trying to remember or are you just hoping there is a word out there somewhere?

Comment: Usually we ask for a sentence in which this word might be used, can you provide one?

Comment: I've retagged this. Please do read our [comprehensive help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for this sort of question. Admittedly , the right tag may not be immediately obvious! I hope it provides some useful information so that your question can be enhanced in order that it can be answered as fully as possible.

Comment: *Core* values are one thing, but who says all paths lead to the center?

Comment: Hub and spoke. All spokes lead to the hub.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean **convergent** paths or activities?

Converge[v.]
If lines, roads, or paths converge, they move towards the same point where they join or meet.

Example:
Ambulances, police cars, and fire engines all converged on the scene.

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/converging

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's generally best to wait for clarification so you don't have to guess. In any case, answers should be corroborated: you need to explain **why** *convergent* fits, preferably with citations from reference books.

Answer (score 0):

The *nexus* is both the center and the linked connection.

## Nexus

> 1: CONNECTION, LINK *the nexus between teachers and students*. also : a causal link *the nexus between poverty and crime*

> 2: a connected group or series. *a nexus of theories* or *a nexus of relationships*

> 3: CENTER, FOCUS. *The bookstore has become something of a nexus for the downtown neighborhood.* — Jane Smiley

Source: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nexus)